# Spatialite database creation problem (QGIS DB manager)

Tags: qgis-plugins, spatialite

I am trying to create a Spatialite database in QGIS 1.8.0. Step one of instructions is:

Right click on the Spatialite entry in the Browser tree and select Create Database.

The Spatialite icon is frozen. It does not respond to right click or anything else.
Anyone who encountered this issue before?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using QGIS 1.8 and not QGIS 2.2? QGIS 2.2 is the most recent version, and there is a great plugin for Spatialite (QspatiaLite) which makes working with, creating, editing, etc. spatialite databases very easy.